# auto close tags in visual studio

Tags: xml, visual-studio

I've an XML document and the tags are not properly closed.

```
<AT2>From the EDITOR 
<H1><B>Spring Fever (At Least For Now)</B>
<P>So far, 2014 looks like the M&A sector’s long-awaited year of recovery. First-quarter 2014 was the strongest start for new deals since 2011, a surge thanks in great part to Comcast’s $45 billion bid for Time Warner Cable. In terms of dollar volume, the amount of worldwide M&A posted was $742.1 billion, up 35% year-over-year compared to first-quarter 2013.
<P>Comcast’s deal unsurprisingly made cable the biggest sector of the M&A universe, with roughly $145 billion in new volume announced in the first three months of 2014, followed by oil and gas ($55 billion), telecom ($49 billion) and internet software/services and pharmaceuticals (each $32 billion), according to Thomson Reuters. The key question, of course, is the nature of this surge of new issuance: how long can it last? Analysts are divided over whether the Comcast deal has distorted an otherwise par-for-the-course market performance or whether the deal is a sign of further multi-billion mergers to come. If the latter, it would make 2014 a welcome exception to the string of mediocre deal volumes that have defined the post-recession era in M&A.
```

here there are some close tags missing, i want to know if this can be done directly. the line where the text ends is where the tag closes. please let me know how can i do this.

Thanks

Comment: your question is not clear, what do u want to do?

Comment: Add the closing tags automatically

Comment: visual studio adds a closing tag when you add an opening tag...

Comment: Yes @SidM, i accept with you, but this is a document that we received not created by us :(